# Cassandra IN condition for a property of time-sorted data

Tags: cassandra

Given I have the following structure of data

```
CREATE TABLE db(
year int,
day int,
deal_id text,
update_dt timestamp,
codes set<text>,
payload text,
PRIMARY KEY ((year, day), update_dt, deal_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (update_dt DESC);
```

And the following data in it

```
 year | day | update_dt                       | deal_id | codes           | payload
------+-----+---------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--------------
 2018 | 231 | 2018-10-30 11:21:59.001000+0000 |     abc |      {'a', 'c'} |   Hi 2 there
 2018 | 231 | 2018-10-30 11:21:59.001000+0000 |    abcd |      {'a', 'c'} | Hi 2 there 3
 2018 | 231 | 2018-10-30 11:21:59.001000+0000 |   abcde |      {'a', 'c'} | Hi 2 there 3
 2018 | 231 | 2018-10-30 11:21:59.001000+0000 |  abcdef | {'a', 'c', 'e'} | Hi 2 there 3
```

Is there any option I could restrict the results of

```
select * from db where year=2018 and day=231 and update_dt < '2018-10-31T11:21:59.001+0000';
```

So that I display only the ones which have certain codes, say 'a' and 'e' which maps to one record with deal_id = abcdef?

If this cannot be achieved with one table alone, how to do it with two? Ordering by update date and the ability to restrict it by date is important.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the range condition only on the last clustering column of your query. In your table design, you cannot do this because `deal_id` is after the `update_dt`...

You can try to change table definition to have primary key like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((year, day), deal_id, update_dt)
```

in this case you could to query like:

```
select * from db where year=2018 and day=231 and deal_id = 'abc' 
   and update_dt < '2018-10-31T11:21:59.001+0000';
```

or

```
select * from db where year=2018 and day=231 and deal_id in ('abc', 'def')
   and update_dt < '2018-10-31T11:21:59.001+0000';
```

Comment: But how do I preserve the order then? And I would need to know the ids right? Unless they are timeuuid...

Comment: But you can use materialized view to avoid writing into 2 tables... But keep in mind - in Cassandra data is modeled about queries, you need to have tables matching them...